# Corruption(?) of the Raspberry Pi Pico's UART characters with the C SDK

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, c, serial, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm making a remote controlled machine using a Raspberry Pi Pico to drive the motors and read some sensors, and a Raspberry Pi 4 to send commands to the Pico via serial and host the web interface.

I am currently testing the operation of the serial from the Pico. To do this I have connected the Pico with the Raspberry Pi 4 in the following way:

[image: WIRING]

I am using the following files:

1. `main.c` to receive and send
2. `ring_queue.h` where the code for the ring queue is located

*main.c*

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/uart.h"
#include "hardware/irq.h"
#include "ring_queue.h"

//DEFINES
#define UART_ID uart0
#define BAUD_RATE 19200
#define DATA_BITS 8
#define STOP_BITS 1
#define PARITY    UART_PARITY_NONE
#define UART_TX_PIN 0
#define UART_RX_PIN 1
#define LED_PIN PICO_DEFAULT_LED_PIN

volatile queue *tx_queue;
volatile queue *rx_queue;

volatile int chars_rxed = 0;
volatile char uCommand[32];

void send_tx(){
  //printf("Joined send_tx\n");
  if(queue_empty((queue*)tx_queue) == 1){
    //printf("Queue empty\n");
    return;
  }
  else{
    printf("Trying to send something\n");
    if(uart_is_writable(UART_ID)){
      printf("%s\n", queue_dequeue((queue*)tx_queue));
      //uart_puts(UART_ID, queue_dequeue(tx_queue));
    }
    else printf("Cannot write\n");
  }
}

void receive_rx(){
  if(queue_full((queue*)rx_queue)){
    printf("Full queue, cannot receive\n");
    return;
  }
  else{
    while(uart_is_readable(UART_ID)){
      char ch = uart_getc(UART_ID);
      printf("Got a ch! %c\n", ch);
      if(ch != 10){
        uCommand[chars_rxed] = ch;
      }
      printf("Should have added it to uCommand: %s\n", uCommand);
      if(uCommand[chars_rxed] == '/'){
        printf("End of the command\n");
        queue_enqueue((queue*)rx_queue, (char*)uCommand);
        chars_rxed = 0;
        break;
      }
      if(ch != 10) chars_rxed++;
    }
  }
}

int main(){

  stdio_init_all();
  uart_init(UART_ID, BAUD_RATE);

  gpio_set_function(UART_TX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);
  gpio_set_function(UART_RX_PIN, GPIO_FUNC_UART);

  uart_set_hw_flow(UART_ID, false, false);

  uart_set_format(UART_ID, DATA_BITS, STOP_BITS, PARITY);

  uart_set_fifo_enabled(UART_ID, false);

  int UART_IRQ = UART_ID == uart0 ? UART0_IRQ : UART1_IRQ;

  irq_set_exclusive_handler(UART_IRQ, receive_rx);
  irq_set_enabled(UART_IRQ, true);

  uart_set_irq_enables(UART_ID, true, false);

  rx_queue = create_queue(32);
  tx_queue = create_queue(32);

  uart_puts(UART_ID, "\nOK\n");

    while (1){
        tight_loop_contents();
        send_tx();
        if(queue_size((queue*)rx_queue) != 0){
          printf("Moving from rx to tx to print the received command\n");
          queue_enqueue((queue*)tx_queue, queue_dequeue((queue*)rx_queue));
        }
    }
}
```

*ring_queue.h*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int tail;      // current tail
    unsigned int head;      // current head
    unsigned int size;      // current number of items
    unsigned int capacity;  // Capacity of queue
    char** data;                // Pointer to array of data
} queue;

queue *create_queue(unsigned int _capacity){
    queue *myQueue = malloc(sizeof(queue));

    if (myQueue == NULL ) return NULL;
    else {
        myQueue->tail = -1;
        myQueue->head = 0;
        myQueue->size = 0;
        myQueue->capacity = _capacity;
        myQueue->data = malloc(_capacity * sizeof(char*));

        return myQueue;
    }
}

int queue_empty(queue *q) {
    if(q == NULL) return -1;
    else if(q->size == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int queue_full(queue *q) {
    if(q == NULL) return -1;
    else if(q->size == q->capacity) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int queue_enqueue(queue *q, const char *item) {
    if (q == NULL) return -1;
    else if (queue_full(q) == 1) return 0;
    else {
      q->tail = (q->tail + 1) % q->capacity;
    q->data[q->tail] = strdup(item);
      q->size++;

      return 1;
    }
}

const char *queue_dequeue(queue *q) {
    if(q == NULL) return NULL;
    else if(queue_empty(q) == 1) return '\0';
    else {
        char *item = q->data[q->head];
        q->head = (q->head + 1) % q->capacity;
        q->size--;

        return item;
    }
}

unsigned int queue_size(queue *q) {
    if (q == NULL) return - 1;
    else return q->size;
}

void free_queue(queue *q) {
  for(int i = 0; i < q->capacity; i++) free(q->data[i]);
  free(q->data);
    free(q);
}
```

I used some prints for debugging (via USB), and when I send a simple command to the Pico (via UART) (consisting of `$` as the initial and / as the final, for example "$MOVE /" ), using the Arduino IDE Serial prompt on the Raspberry Pi 4, I get the following output:

**usb stdio**

Got a ch! ¢

Should have added it to uCommand: ùK9Ë±ËAÿ¢

Also it does not send the 'OK' when I start the serial prompt but it sends some random chars and strangely enough it was working properly yesterday.

At first I thought it was a problem with the baud rate, but I rule that out since it is set correctly both on the serial prompt and in the code...

Comment: Have you tested this without queuing? Also, it looks like the uCommand c-string is not properly zero-terminated which might cause issues with the queueing algorithm.

Comment: Hi StarCat, how should I 'zero-terminate' uCommand? Also, it does not print uCommand ( main.c, receive_rx()) either, even though it is not in the queue, so I doubt that the queue algorithm is a problem...

Comment: A [c-string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm), like uCommand, is simply a char array that's terminated by  a '\0' (null byte). AFAIK there's nothing in your `receive_rx()` code that ensures that the last character of the uCommand string, after receiving a complete command, is a '\0'. The queuing (enqueue) algorithm uses `strdup()` which relies on the c-string being terminated with a '\0'. It was just an observation and it might not have caused the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: So basically I should set uCommand[31] = '\0'?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but will probably bite you: there's no need to cast a value that's already the expected type to pass to a prototyped function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. by switching the uart from 19200 to 115200 it worked. Probably, by using it in a area full of cables they messed up the the communication.

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer. However I doubt that the true cause has been understood. If: "*switching the uart from 19200 to 115200 it worked*" then "*by using it in a area full of cables they messed up the the communication*" was not that cause. Cable related physical issues e.g. capacitance, externally noise (EMI) affect faster data rates *more* than slower data rates. So that is not an explanation of why a faster data rate "solved" the problem. Therefore I am concerned that the *true* cause has not been found here, which could be very relevant for your [next question](/questions/581791).